# Amplitude, period, and phase angle of f(t) = - cos(t) + 3sin(t-pi/6)

Tags: function, trigonometry

I have a function 
`f(t) = -cos(t) + 3sin(t-pi/6)` I am trying to find the amplitude, period, and phase angle. But, I am under the impression that because the arguments are different in each trig function the function do not map simple harmonic motion. Is this right?

If the arguments of my compound function matched I would use the identity, `acos(t) + bsin(t) = Asin(wt + g) = Asin(wt)cos(g) + Acos(wt)sin(g)`, therefor since this is a linear combination, the coefficients must match. Solved. If someone would be able to illuminate where I am misunderstanding it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-cos%28t%29+%2B+3sin%28t-pi%2F6%29

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Since for all x ∈ ℝ

```
sin(x) ≡ cos(x - ½π)
cos(x) ≡ sin(x + ½π)
```

you can rewrite `f(t)` as

```
f(t) = -cos(t) + 3·sin(t - π/6)
     = -1·cos(t) + 3·cos(t - 4·π/6)
```

Then `f(t)` is basically a [phasor addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#Addition), so that you can transform this into

```
f(t) = A · cos(t + φ),
```

with

```
A = √13
φ = arctan( 3/5·√3 ) - π
```

So, your amplitude is √13, your phase angle is arctan( 3/5·√3 ) - π, and your period is simply 2π.